# How to move LocalDb database to SQL Server database on the hosting server for ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have built an application with ASP.NET MVC 5 using Entity Framework 6, code-first workflow in Visual Studio 2013 Express. The application works fine on the local host.

Below is is my connection string before publishing:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ERPCLINIC-20170908103952.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ERPCLINIC-20170908103952;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="SchoolContext" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ERPCLINIC.mdf;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Those are contained in the `web.config` on the local host server.

And below is my connection string after publishing:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=197.189.255.211 (MS SQL Server);Initial Catalog=qffienta_mat;User Id=qffienta_qffienta;Password=4uOHj7da65;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="SchoolContext" 
         connectionString="Data Source=197.189.255.211 (MS SQL Server);Initial Catalog=qffienta_mat;User Id=qffienta_qffienta;Password=4uOHj7da65;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Again, those are contained in the `web.config` on the hosting server.

I get the following error when trying to launch my application in my domain:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> No connection string named 'SchoolContext_DatabasePublish' could be found in the application config file.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: No connection string named 'SchoolContext_DatabasePublish' could be found in the application config file.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 5:      var db = new SchoolContext();
>   Line 6:
>   Line 7:      var mostRecentEntries =
>   Line 8:          (from entry in db.Appointments
>   Line 9:           orderby entry.ID descending
>
> Source File:
>   c:\Websites\qffientasp.co.za\httpdocs\Views\Shared_Appointment.cshtml
>   Line: 7  "

I deploy it with Visual Studio 2013 Express to my hosting account, publishing was successful, but when I tried to access it on my domain it seems it can't connect to the database. I don't now what might be the problem. I created a new database from hosting account which I am trying connect to.

Answer (score 0):

Error tells true:

> No connection string named 'SchoolContext_DatabasePublish' could be
>   found in the application config file.

Where is in your connectionStrings section a connection with that name? Also why do you have '(MS SQL Server)' in your connection string? There should be ip(,port) or db server name(/instance name).

Try exactly specify the connection name in constructor:

```
public SchoolContext : base("SchoolContext")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much. problem was i put server name wrongly. I created two new database in my remote server and my connection string look like:

```
 <add name="SchoolContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=197.189.255.211;Initial Catalog=qffienta_tar;User Id=qffienta_tar;Password=4uOHj7da65;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Hope this will help some other people, to publish your application you only need to change connection strings to match your new database, user id and password as i did above, if you are publishing with visual studio 2013 using web deploy, on database, remote connection strings, you enter something like:

Data Source=server name;Initial Catalog=database name;User Id=username;Password=your password;

I spent two days trying to figure out how to deploy my application on server.